# Create a "negate" wrapper for a type_traits class

Tags: c++, templates, metaprogramming, template-meta-programming, type-traits

Let's say I have a `Filter` metafunction that filters a list of types:

```
template<template<typename> class TFilter, typename... Ts> 
using Filter = MetaList</* check TFilter<T>{}() for every type in Ts... */>;
```

The metafunction can be used like this:

```
Filter<std::is_pod, int, char, std::string, int>
// ...returns...
MetaList<int, char, int>
```

Now, I'd like to get all types that are not POD. I could create a `FilterNot` metafunction, but I actually need the "negation" in other metafunctions as well.

Is it possible to create a negation wrapper for any **type-trait**-like template class?

Desired code:

```
Filter<Negate<std::is_pod>, int, char, std::string, int>
// ...returns...
MetaList<std::string>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
template<template<class...>class Z>
struct negate {
  template<class...Ts>
  using result=std::integral_constant<bool, !Z<Ts...>::value>;
};
Filter<negate<std::is_pod>:: template result, int, char, std::string, int>;
```

or

```
Filter<typename negate<std::is_pod>::result, int, char, std::string, int>;
```

depending on compiler should work.  (IIRC, some compilers are quirky about this)

As I find this syntax awkward, maybe take a list of tests to daisy chain?  Then negation is just another trait on the stack:

```
template<template<class...>class... Zs>
struct tests {};
```

then take a `tests` and apply the `Zs` recursively.

```
template<class B>
using negate=std::integral_constant<bool,!B::value>;

filters<tests<negate, std::is_pod>, int, std::string>
```

Yet another approach is to take your tests and make them constexpr functions on `tag<type>{}` (easy to do), which are syntactically easier to compose.  Going from `template<class>class` to `constexpr bool(tag<class>)` isn't hard.

Comment: You could write `!Z<Ts...>{}` instead of `!Z<Ts...>::value` (see the comment in the question: `/* check TFilter<T>{}() for every type in Ts... */`).

Comment: @constructor agreed, but figured the `constexpr` support requirement wasn't worth it (first version used that exact syntax).

Comment: Ah, `constexpr`... Its support is like a thing which you stumble again and again over.

Comment: Works both on clang 3.5 and gcc 4.9.2, which are my target compilers. Great!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
using namespace std;

template<template <class> class P>
struct invert
{
  template<class... Args>
  struct templ {
    static constexpr bool value = ! P<Args...>::value;
  };
};



int main()
{
  cout << invert<is_pod>::templ<string>::value << endl;
  cout << is_pod<string>::value << endl;

  return 0;
}
```